# Converting string to title case

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which contains words in a mixture of upper and lower case characters.

For example: `string myData = "a Simple string";`

I need to convert the first character of each word (separated by spaces) into upper case. So I want the result as: `string myData ="A Simple String";`

Is there any easy way to do this? I don't want to split the string and do the conversion (that will be my last resort). Also, it is guaranteed that the strings are in English.

Comment: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890) - How to convert strings to lower, upper, or title (proper) case by using Visual C#

Answer (score 651, accepted):

MSDN : [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase)

Make sure that you include: `using System.Globalization`

```
string title = "war and peace";

TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

title = textInfo.ToTitleCase(title); 
Console.WriteLine(title) ; //War And Peace

//When text is ALL UPPERCASE...
title = "WAR AND PEACE" ;

title = textInfo.ToTitleCase(title); 
Console.WriteLine(title) ; //WAR AND PEACE

//You need to call ToLower to make it work
title = textInfo.ToTitleCase(title.ToLower()); 
Console.WriteLine(title) ; //War And Peace
```

Comment: Title case won't strictly convert EVERY word to have an uppercase starting letter, for example: and,but,or etc will remain lower. But I assume this is what you want anyway

Comment: True. Also, if a word is all upper case it doesn't work. eg - "an FBI agent shot my DOG" - > "An FBI Agent Shot My DOG". And it doesn't handle "McDonalds", and so forth.

Comment: @Kirschstein this function *does* conver these words to title case, even though they shouldn't be in English. See the documentation: `Actual result: "War And Peace"`.

Comment: The first letter is made uppercase, everything else is lowered. so McDonalds, O'Neil  = Mcdonalds, O'neal. I need a function to only change the first character of a word, and leave the rest.

Comment: @simbolo - I did actuallt mention it in a comment... You can use something like `text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!\S)\p{Ll}", m => m.Value.ToUpper());`, but it is far from perfect. For example, it still doesn't handle quotes or parentheses - `"(one two three)"` -> `"(one Two Three)"`. You may want to ask a new question after you figure out exactly what you want to do with these cases.

Comment: @Kobi I'm doing names of people, so "the" and "and" don't really factor in, but O'Patrick does. I ended up with `Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), @"\b[a-z]",
                                 m => m.Value.ToUpper())`, but I may have fix it for the McDonald case. **Edit:** @simbolo can remove the `ToLower()` if he only wants to change the first letter.

Comment: For some reason when I have "DR" it doesn't become "Dr" unless I call .ToLower() first before calling ToTitleCase()... So that's something to watch out for...

Comment: A .ToLower() to input string is required if the input text is in upper case

Comment: Thank you @TodThomson I was using the ToTitleCase Method and it wasn't working on the entries I had that were all caps. The ToLower first made it work!!

Comment: @TodThomson - this is documented behavior: [TextInfo.TitleCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx) - "a word that is entirely uppercase, such as an acronym, is not converted."

Comment: @TodThomson The reason is that "title-case" is a language-specific construct, with funny rules. I added clarifying information to the answer; but, FTR, "War And Peace" is *not* actually title case, according to common English usage: it should be "War and Peace"

Comment: @jpaugh - I rolled back your edit - there is already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342519/7586) with the same code.

Comment: @Kobi Neither answer has a decent explanation of *why* `ToLower()` can be necessary or unwanted; and I am loathe to add yet another answer. Nevertheless, I'll respect your intent for this post.

Comment: TextInfo is part of System.Globalization

Comment: Only available for  .NET Framework 4.7.2 <= your frame work <= .NET Core 2.0

Comment: @PaulGorbas - I don't really understand your notation to be honest (should it have been `>= .NET Core 2.0`?). According to [`ToTitleCase` > Applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to), the function is available in .Net Core 2.0 and up - there is a gap of .Net Core 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: I am not in the US so I wondered what code to use in cultureinfo.  I found a few places that listed the values but this is important https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0 -  The name is a combination of an ISO 639 two-letter lowercase culture code associated with a language and an ISO 3166 two-letter UPPERCASE subculture code associated with a country or region.

Answer (score 151):

Try this:

```
string myText = "a Simple string";

string asTitleCase =
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.
    ToTitleCase(myText.ToLower());
```

As has already been pointed out, using TextInfo.ToTitleCase might not give you the exact results you want. If you need more control over the output, you could do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<char> CharsToTitleCase(string s)
{
    bool newWord = true;
    foreach(char c in s)
    {
        if(newWord) { yield return Char.ToUpper(c); newWord = false; }
        else yield return Char.ToLower(c);
        if(c==' ') newWord = true;
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
var asTitleCase = new string( CharsToTitleCase(myText).ToArray() );
```

Comment: I tried several variations of the TextInfo object - no errors but the original string (upper case) was never updated. Plugged this method in and am very appreciative.

Comment: @justSteve, from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "However, this method does not currently provide proper casing to convert a word that is entirely uppercase, such as an acronym" - you should probably just ToLower() it first (I know this is old, but just in case someone else stumbles on it and wonders why!)

Comment: Only available for .NET Framework 4.7.2 <= your frame work <= .NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 91):

Yet another variation. Based on several tips here I've reduced it to this extension method, which works great for my purposes:

```
public static string ToTitleCase(this string s) =>
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());
```

Comment: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());  would be a better fit actually!

Comment: Only available for .NET Framework 4.7.2 <= your frame work <= .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Since we are using InvariantCulture for TitleCasing, s.ToLowerInvariant() should be used instead of s.ToLower().

Answer (score 28):

Personally I tried the `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` method, but, I don´t understand why it doesn´t work when all chars are upper-cased.

Though I like the util function provided by [Winston Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206030/1203135), let me provide the function I'm currently using:

```
public static String TitleCaseString(String s)
{
    if (s == null) return s;

    String[] words = s.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].Length == 0) continue;

        Char firstChar = Char.ToUpper(words[i][0]); 
        String rest = "";
        if (words[i].Length > 1)
        {
            rest = words[i].Substring(1).ToLower();
        }
        words[i] = firstChar + rest;
    }
    return String.Join(" ", words);
}
```

Playing with some **tests** strings:

```
String ts1 = "Converting string to title case in C#";
String ts2 = "C";
String ts3 = "";
String ts4 = "   ";
String ts5 = null;

Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("|{0}|", TitleCaseString(ts1)));
Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("|{0}|", TitleCaseString(ts2)));
Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("|{0}|", TitleCaseString(ts3)));
Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("|{0}|", TitleCaseString(ts4)));
Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("|{0}|", TitleCaseString(ts5)));
```

Giving **output**:

```
|Converting String To Title Case In C#|
|C|
||
|   |
||
```

Comment: solution to "why it doesn´t work when all chars are upper-cased?"
You should first your input string to lower case

Comment: @harsh : "ugly" solution I would say... makes no sense for me that you have first to convert the whole string to lower-case.

Comment: It's intentional, because if you ask for, say, "UNICEF and charity" to be title-cased, you don't want it to be changed to Unicef.

Comment: the function takes the first character of each word, delimeted after a space character, and make it upper case, it doesnt affect any of the othert characters, hence when they are uppercase they remain uppercase.  With todays powerful computers, making something .tolower() isn't going to cause any trouble, ever.

Comment: @nitro you can do '.tolower()' first, sure, I'm not saying is any trouble on it, however it is not *my* desired solution.

Comment: So instead of calling `ToLower()` on the entire string, you'd rather do all of that work yourself and call the same function on each individual character? Not only is it an ugly solution, it is giving zero benefit, and would even take longer than the built-in function.

Comment: @krillgar: clarify where in my code you understand that: 'call the same function on each individual character'.

Comment: `rest = words[i].Substring(1).ToLower();`

Comment: @ruffin No. [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_) with a single int parameter starts at the given index, and returns everything to the end of the string.

Comment: @krillgar Argh. True. That was dumb. Still might be worth the optimization check to see what we're really talking about ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/2f57d11ecc36d11c06fc862dcb0de37c96d305d2/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/CaseInsensitiveComparison.cs#L303), maybe?) with performance.

Answer (score 25):

Recently I found a better solution.

If your text contains every letter in uppercase, then **TextInfo** will not convert it to the proper case. We can fix that by using the lowercase function inside like this:

```
public static string ConvertTo_ProperCase(string text)
{
    TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    return myTI.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());
}
```

Now this will convert everything that comes in to Propercase.

Answer (score 18):

```
public static string PropCase(string strText)
{
    return new CultureInfo("en").TextInfo.ToTitleCase(strText.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: I like that you added the ToLower prior to ToTitleCase, covers the situation where the input text is all caps.

Answer (score 17):

Use `ToLower()` first, and then `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase` on the result to get the correct output.

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get title case of a string (every word with leading upper case,
    //                             the rest is lower case)
    //    i.e: ABCD EFG -> Abcd Efg,
    //         john doe -> John Doe,
    //         miXEd CaSING - > Mixed Casing
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    public static string ToTitleCase(string str)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If someone is interested for the solution for Compact Framework :

```
return String.Join(" ", thestring.Split(' ').Select(i => i.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + i.Substring(1).ToLower()).ToArray());
```

Comment: With the string interpolation :

    return string.Join(" ",
        text.Split(' ')
            .Select(i => $"{i.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()}{i.Substring(1).ToLower()}")
            .ToArray());

Answer (score 6):

Here's the solution for that problem...

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
string txt = textInfo.ToTitleCase(txt);
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed a way to deal with all caps words, and I liked Ricky AH's solution, but I took it a step further to implement it as an extension method. This avoids the step of having to create your array of chars then call ToArray on it explicitly every time - so you can just call it on the string, like so:

usage:

```
string newString = oldString.ToProper();
```

code:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToProper(this string s)
    {
        return new string(s.CharsToTitleCase().ToArray());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<char> CharsToTitleCase(this string s)
    {
        bool newWord = true;
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (newWord) { yield return Char.ToUpper(c); newWord = false; }
            else yield return Char.ToLower(c);
            if (c == ' ') newWord = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just added one more OR condition if (c == ' ' || c == '\'')...sometimes names do contain apostrophes (').

Comment: Perfect! I like it

Answer (score 4):

I used the above references and a complete solution is:

```
Use Namespace System.Globalization;
string str = "INFOA2Z means all information";
```

// Need result like "Infoa2z Means All Information"
// We need to convert the string in lowercase also, otherwise it is not working properly.

```
TextInfo ProperCase = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

str = ProperCase.ToTitleCase(str.toLower());
```

*[Change string to proper case in an ASP.NET Using C#](http://www.infoa2z.com/asp.net/change-string-to-proper-case-in-an-asp.net-using-c#)*

Answer (score 2):

Its better to understand by trying your own code...

Read more

http://www.stupidcodes.com/2014/04/convert-string-to-uppercase-proper-case.html

**1) Convert a String to Uppercase**

```
string lower = "converted from lowercase";
Console.WriteLine(lower.ToUpper());
```

**2) Convert a String to Lowercase**

```
string upper = "CONVERTED FROM UPPERCASE";
Console.WriteLine(upper.ToLower());
```

**3) Convert a String to TitleCase**

```
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
    string txt = textInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text());
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative with reference to [`Microsoft.VisualBasic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.strconv) (handles uppercase strings too):

```
string properCase = Strings.StrConv(str, VbStrConv.ProperCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why this is not in the answer list: Here is the one liner

```cs
string input = "this string will be converted into title case";
    var titleCase = string.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').Select(i => $"{i.Remove(1).ToUpper()}{i.Substring(1).ToLower()}"));
    titleCase.Dump();
Console.WriteLine(titleCase);
```

this is without any dependency even without `using System.Globalization`.

**Note: *If you change the `Remove(1)` & `Substring(1)` character from 1 to 2 it will make first two character capital and so on***

### How it works ?

1. The `input.Remove(1)` extracts the first character which is `t` in the example above and converts it in upper case using `ToUpper()` which makes `T`
2. `input.Substring(1)` removes the first character from the `input` in example
3. The result from 1 & 2 are concerted with `$"{} {}"` to form the result

#### How to use

This can be crafted as **Func** as

```cs
Func<string,string> TitleCase = (ins) =>{ 
        return string.Join(" ", ins.Split(' ').Select(i => $"{i.Remove(1).ToUpper()}{i.Substring(1).ToLower()}")); 
    };

Console.WriteLine(TitleCase(input));
```

Or as an **Extension function**

```cs
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string input)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').Select(i => $"{i.Remove(1).ToUpper()}{i.Substring(1).ToLower()}"));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(input.ToTitleCase());
```

[image]

Comment: It is not in the answer list because it doesn't answer the question, which was to capitalise the first letter of each word (Proper Case or Title Case), not just the first letter of the sentence/string (Sentence case).

Comment: @SlyGryphon Thanks for pointing that out, see if the updated answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation, character by character. It should work with "(One Two Three)":

```
public static string ToInitcap(this string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return str;
    char[] charArray = new char[str.Length];
    bool newWord = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
    {
        Char currentChar = str[i];
        if (Char.IsLetter(currentChar))
        {
            if (newWord)
            {
                newWord = false;
                currentChar = Char.ToUpper(currentChar);
            }
            else
            {
                currentChar = Char.ToLower(currentChar);
            }
        }
        else if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(currentChar))
        {
            newWord = true;
        }
        charArray[i] = currentChar;
    }
    return new string(charArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String TitleCaseString(String s)
{
    if (s == null || s.Length == 0) return s;

    string[] splits = s.Split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (splits[i].Length)
        {
            case 1:
                break;

            default:
                splits[i] = Char.ToUpper(splits[i][0]) + splits[i].Substring(1);
                break;
        }
    }

    return String.Join(" ", splits);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly change text or string to proper using this simple method, after checking for null or empty string values in order to eliminate errors:

```
// Text to proper (Title Case):
    public string TextToProper(string text)
    {
        string ProperText = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            ProperText = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text);
        }
        else
        {
            ProperText = string.Empty;
        }
        return ProperText;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `TextInfo`:

```
public static string TitleCase(this string text, char seperator = ' ') =>
  string.Join(seperator, text.Split(seperator).Select(word => new string(
    word.Select((letter, i) => i == 0 ? char.ToUpper(letter) : char.ToLower(letter)).ToArray())));
```

It loops through every letter in each word, converting it to uppercase if it's the first letter otherwise converting it to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
public void ToTitleCase(TextBox TextBoxName)
        {
            int TextLength = TextBoxName.Text.Length;
            if (TextLength == 1)
            {
                CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
                TextBoxName.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxName.Text);
                TextBoxName.SelectionStart = 1;
            }
            else if (TextLength > 1 && TextBoxName.SelectionStart < TextLength)
            {
                int x = TextBoxName.SelectionStart;
                CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
                TextBoxName.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxName.Text);
                TextBoxName.SelectionStart = x;
            }
            else if (TextLength > 1 && TextBoxName.SelectionStart >= TextLength)
            {
                CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
                TextBoxName.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBoxName.Text);
                TextBoxName.SelectionStart = TextLength;
            }
        }
```

Call this method in the TextChanged event of the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use and it works for most cases unless the user decides to override it by pressing shift or caps lock. Like on Android and iOS keyboards.

```
Private Class ProperCaseHandler
    Private Const wordbreak As String = " ,.1234567890;/\-()#$%^&*€!~+=@"
    Private txtProperCase As TextBox

    Sub New(txt As TextBox)
        txtProperCase = txt
        AddHandler txt.KeyPress, AddressOf txtTextKeyDownProperCase
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtTextKeyDownProperCase(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        Try
            If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Or Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                If txtProperCase.TextLength = 0 Then
                    e.KeyChar = e.KeyChar.ToString.ToUpper()
                    e.Handled = False
                Else
                    Dim lastChar As String = txtProperCase.Text.Substring(txtProperCase.SelectionStart - 1, 1)

                    If wordbreak.Contains(lastChar) = True Then
                        e.KeyChar = e.KeyChar.ToString.ToUpper()
                        e.Handled = False
                    End If
                End If

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who are looking to do it automatically on keypress, I did it with following code in VB.NET on a custom textboxcontrol - you can obviously also do it with a normal textbox - but I like the possibility to add recurring code for specific controls via custom controls it suits the concept of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyTextBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Private LastKeyIsNotAlpha As Boolean = True
    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If _ProperCasing Then
            Dim c As Char = e.KeyChar
            If Char.IsLetter(c) Then
                If LastKeyIsNotAlpha Then
                    e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(c)
                    LastKeyIsNotAlpha = False
                End If
            Else
                LastKeyIsNotAlpha = True
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
End Sub
    Private _ProperCasing As Boolean = False
    <Category("Behavior"), Description("When Enabled ensures for automatic proper casing of string"), Browsable(True)>
    Public Property ProperCasing As Boolean
        Get
            Return _ProperCasing
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _ProperCasing = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine even with camel case: 'someText in YourPage'

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Title case example: 'Some Text In Your Page'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">Support camel and title cases combinations: 'someText in YourPage'</param>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return text;
        }
        var result = string.Empty;
        var splitedBySpace = text.Split(new[]{ ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var sequence in splitedBySpace)
        {
            // let's check the letters. Sequence can contain even 2 words in camel case
            for (var i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
            {
                var letter = sequence[i].ToString();
                // if the letter is Big or it was spaced so this is a start of another word
                if (letter == letter.ToUpper() || i == 0)
                {
                    // add a space between words
                    result += ' ';
                }
                result += i == 0 ? letter.ToUpper() : letter;
            }
        }
        return result.Trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension method:

```
/// <summary>
//     Returns a copy of this string converted to `Title Case`.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The string to convert.</param>
/// <returns>The `Title Case` equivalent of the current string.</returns>
public static string ToTitleCase(this string value)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        char p = i == 0 ? char.MinValue : value[i - 1];
        char c = value[i];

        result += char.IsLetter(c) && ((p is ' ') || p is char.MinValue) ? $"{char.ToUpper(c)}" : $"{char.ToLower(c)}";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
"kebab is DELICIOU's   ;d  c...".ToTitleCase();
```

Result:

`Kebab Is Deliciou's   ;d  C...`

Answer (score -1):

A way to do it in C:

```
char proper(char string[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<=25; i++)
    {
        string[i] = tolower(string[i]);  // Converts all characters to lower case
        if(string[i-1] == ' ') // If the character before is a space
        {
            string[i] = toupper(string[i]); // Converts characters after spaces to upper case
        }
    }

    string[0] = toupper(string[0]); // Converts the first character to upper case
    return 0;
}
```