# Improve string camelization method

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-in-c)

I want to "camelize" a string, for example:

- PARTS/ACESSORIES -> Parts/Accessories
- HELLO WORLD/TEST -> Hello World/Test
- Hello World -> Hello World

Here's what i have so far:

```
  public static string Camelize(this string str)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return "";

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] chars = str.ToLower().ToCharArray();
        bool upper = true;            
        // ' ', '-', '.', '/'
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; ++i)
        {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (i == 0 || //First char 
                chars[i - 1] == ' ' ||
                chars[i - 1] == '-' ||
                chars[i - 1] == '.' ||
                chars[i - 1] == '/'
                ) upper = true;

            if (upper)             
                sb.Append(Char.ToUpper(c));                
            else                
                sb.Append(c);

            upper = false;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Is there any way to improve this method, also I know that strings will not exceed 250 chars?
Thanks

Comment: Your method is misnamed: The string isn't camelized, it's converted to title case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
    public static string Camelize(string text)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());
    }
```

Comment: +1 This is why I love SO, to find these lovely gems.

Comment: +1, I always forget this method exists...

Comment: As LukeH this is not 'Camelize', it's converted to title case. Camelize will be "Hello World" -> "hello World"