# How to split a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string. Example:

```
Eternal (woman)
```

I want to make it `Eternal (Woman)`.

How I can do this in C#?

If I split by  string[] mean = `inf.Meaning.Split('(');` then I can't get `(`.

Comment: you want to split or capitalize? i don't understand the question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-in-c)

Comment: Arnis: Why? Have you figured out what, exactly, is being asked here?

Comment: Also check out this other SO question: [Converting string to title clase in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case-in-c).

Comment: You posted something along these lines about an hour ago and then deleted it. Sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example data doesn't need to be split at all to achieve the desired results:

```
string foo = "Eternal (woman)";
string bar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(foo);

Console.WriteLine(bar);    // "Eternal (Woman)"
```

Is your real data any different? Do you actually need to split the string for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string str = "Eternal (woman)";
        string[] s = str.Split('(');

        string newString = string.Empty;
        foreach (string sUpper in s)
        {
            newString += UppercaseFirst(sUpper);
        }
        newString = newString.Replace(" " ," (");
    }

    static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
    {
        // Check for empty string.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        // Return char and concat substring.
        return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

You can also do:

```
"Eternal (woman)".Replace('w','W');
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake there in the second code section. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split. The only thing that happens in your sample data is that `w` has been capitalized. Thus, this does what you want:

```
"Eternal (woman)".Replace('w', 'W');
```

But I do urge you to update the question; add some context.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the methods of the String class. Perhaps that will help determine what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 string breakMe =   "Eternal (woman)";
 string [] split = breakMe.Split( ' ' );
```

Would do what you are asking.

There are also other options one of which is with [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx).

```
 string[] lines = Regex.Split(breakMe, "FANCY REGEX" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to split it into an array and than trim and capitalize first character.

```
public static string doStaffSplit(string s) {

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  foreach(string word in s.Spilt('(') {
      sb.Append(String.format("({0}",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word.Trim()));

  }

 return sb.ToString();

}
```

To capitalize

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("string")' //res String

Should work, not tested.

Comment: do you mean `s.Split(' ')`? There aren't any semicolons in the OP's string.