# convert string to title case with non-English chars (unicode)

Tags: c#, unicode

Im trying to convert non-English string  (greek) to title string 
I did try as this link suggest but with no luck, all the chars got Upper case
[Converting string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case-in-c-sharp)

how can i work with Unicode chars ?

Comment: Did you use TextInfo for greek culture?

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  Surely you can post a small snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @mmix It doesn't matter what culture as if Greek letters are used in a non-Greek language like English or French, then Π is still the upper-case form of π and so on. The idea is to handle more rules than the default such as in en-US ijssel would TitleCase to Ijssel but in nl-NL it would TitleCase to IJssel. Unfortunately, this is ignored by the current over-simple implementation (the documentation notes this as linguistically incorrect, but fast, and reserves the right to change to a more accurate algorithm in the future).

Comment: In the meantime, dont' run ToTileCase on the Irish form of the Lord's Prayer as it'll turn "Ár nAthair" ("Our Father") into "Ár Nathair" ("Our Snake"), which may not go down to well with certain demographics...!

Answer (score 1):

All chars are Unicode chars. We English speakers don't use magical non-Unicode chars from another universe, nor are char characters used in English so obscure as to not be in Unicode yet.

You don't detail precisely what you tried with TextInfo, and the answer you link to isn't very detailed. When I try:

```
CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("English here, then some Greek: Ποικιλόθρον', ἀθάνατ' ἀφρόδιτα, παῖ δίος, δολόπλοκε, λίσσομαί σε μή μ' ἄσαισι μήτ' ὀνίαισι δάμνα, πότνια, θῦμον·")
```

I get back:

```
English Here, Then Some Greek: Ποικιλόθρον', Ἀθάνατ' Ἀφρόδιτα, Παῖ Δίος, Δολόπλοκε, Λίσσομαί Σε Μή Μ' Ἄσαισι Μήτ' Ὀνίαισι Δάμνα, Πότνια, Θῦμον·
```

However, if I start with upper-case:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("ENGLISH HERE, THEN SOME GREEK: ΠΟΙΚΙΛΌΘΡΟΝ', ἈΘΆΝΑΤ' ἈΦΡΌΔΙΤΑ, ΠΑῖ ΔΊΟΣ, ΔΟΛΌΠΛΟΚΕ, ΛΊΣΣΟΜΑΊ ΣΕ ΜΉ Μ' ἌΣΑΙΣΙ ΜΉΤ' ὈΝΊΑΙΣΙ ΔΆΜΝΑ, ΠΌΤΝΙΑ, ΘῦΜΟΝ·")
```

I all upper-case like you describe. Are you also starting with upper-case?

Title case leaves all-upper-case words untouched to avoid damaging acronyms and abbreviations like ".NET", "NATO", "ΙΧΘΥΣ", etc. If you need to deal with this, do ToLower first:

```
var ti = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
return ti.ToTitleCase(ti.ToLower("ENGLISH HERE, THEN SOME GREEK: ΠΟΙΚΙΛΌΘΡΟΝ', ἈΘΆΝΑΤ' ἈΦΡΌΔΙΤΑ, ΠΑῖ ΔΊΟΣ, ΔΟΛΌΠΛΟΚΕ, ΛΊΣΣΟΜΑΊ ΣΕ ΜΉ Μ' ἌΣΑΙΣΙ ΜΉΤ' ὈΝΊΑΙΣΙ ΔΆΜΝΑ, ΠΌΤΝΙΑ, ΘῦΜΟΝ·"));
```

Comment: Ed, what happened at the start of this answer? Did you intend to copy the entire question?

Comment: @jwiscarson Not sure what happened there! The only bit I wanted to copy-paste was the bit that's duplicated within the answer itself. Must have been a mis-click selecting the whole page.

Comment: so i just didnt understand what is the solution ?

Comment: First try converting to lower-case, before you call `ToTitleCase` on it. This will suck when it comes to sigma's if you have any ALL-CAPS words ending with sigma, in which case you'll have to fix it up yourself. If so, take heart that at least it isn't an anti-Greek thing, `ToTitleCase` is an over-simplistic approach that has problems with every language. It's actually easier to fix for Greek that for some other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Greek is not the easiest case for the ToTitleCase linguistically.

```
TextInfo ti = new CultureInfo("el-GR", false).TextInfo;
```

experiment 1:

```
Console.WriteLine(ti.ToTitleCase("εθνικό χρέος"));
```

the output is: **Εθνικό Χρέος**

experiment 2:

```
Console.WriteLine(ti.ToTitleCase("ΕΘΝΙΚΟ ΧΡΕΟΣ"));
```

the output is: **ΕΘΝΙΚΟ ΧΡΕΟΣ**

experiment 3:

```
Console.WriteLine(ti.ToTitleCase("ΕΘΝΙΚΟ ΧΡΕΟΣ".ToLower()));
```

the output is: **Εθνικο Χρεοσ**

Output 1 and 3 are different. Output 3 is missing the diacritics (tonos in Greek) at **ό** and **έ** and uses **σ** at the end of a word instead of **ς** (final s - teliko sigma in Greek). According to the above results, I suggest you to title case only lowered case phrases and leave the uppercase ones as they are, because the result will have for sure many mistakes that your Greek audience will not like. Alternatively you can find a Greek guy to help you on results linguistic accuracy.
For the record "εθνικό χρέος" means national debt - the primary reason to move to another not just country but continent with my family.

Comment: Your capitalised form is ΕΘΝΙΚΟ ΧΡΕΟΣ (U+039F GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMICRON) rather than ΕΘΝΙΚΌ ΧΡΈΟΣ (U+038C GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMICRON WITH TONOS). Granted tonos isn't generally shown with capitals - the above look identical on my system, but it's there in the result to `ti.ToUpper("Εθνικό Χρέος")` so `Console.WriteLine(ti.ToTitleCase("Εθνικό Χρέος".ToUpper().ToLower()));` works correctly.
The problem with medial and final sigmas is still there of course. Still, the code handles Greek as well as Dutch or German, and better than Irish - at least it doesn't change meaning!

Comment: Correct. But this is on purpose as you will never find a Greek originated phrase in upper case with diacritics.

Comment: Yes. It's like accents in French (well there are documented cases of French writers using accents on capitals, but that style is rare enough that many French people will tell you otherwise - I once met someone who just finished a linguistic survey in which every native French speaker he asked said there were never accents on capitals and on his way home saw a massive poster in all-capitals with accents!) Off-the-topic I know, but was it always that way? I know in some languages capitals lost accents because it was easier to do old-style printing and typing that way. Is it the same in Greek?

Comment: It was always like this. There is a joke with a greek-us guy who returned to Greece after many years and read the phrase "ΜΟΚΕΤΕΣ-ΧΑΛΙΑ" as "μοκέτες χάλια" instead of "μοκέτες χαλιά" - meaning "crap carpets" instead of "carpets-rugs" - and was asking the shop owner for the recipe of success by selling crap carpets.

Comment: LOL. See my comment on the question about capitalising the Christian "Lord's Prayer" in Irish. That one's worse in a way as a human would never do it that way but a computer might. Your joke is a bit closer to the concern caused by the English-language Polish-American newspaper that talked about as storn in Poland with HIGH WINDS BLOWS DOWN HUNDREDS OF POLES.

Comment: Sometimes it is even worse with humans. Few weeks ago the hot topic for Greece was the partial debt write-off. This is a common term that in slag Greek is kourema (κούρεμα). Kourema in format Greek means haircut. As a result the national TV satellite channel was full of haircuts in English subtitles.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5766/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-drdigit)

Comment: Thanks for the responses but i still didn't understand what is the solution ?

Comment: use totitle only when the source string is in lowercase otherwise you will have a lot of annoying errors for your greek audience. OR create a project for a coder you knows greek and can write a specific piece of code covering your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the question if it's always in sentence case when it comes in but if you need to split in addition to Title case the string, maybe this method might help you get started.

```
private static string ToTitleCase(string example)
{
    var fromSnakeCase = example.Replace("_", " ");
    var lowerToUpper = Regex.Replace(fromSnakeCase, @"(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})", "$1 $2");
    var sentenceCase = Regex.Replace(lowerToUpper, @"(\p{Lu}+)(\p{Lu}\p{Ll})", "$1 $2");
    return new CultureInfo("el-GR", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sentenceCase);
}
```