# Transform string to title case

Tags: c#

I need to convert to title case the following:

1. First word in a phrase;
2. Other words, in the same phrase, which length is greater than minLength.

I was looking at [ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) but the result is not the expected.

So the phrase "the car is very fast" with minLength = 2 would become "The Car is Very 
Fast".

I was able to make the first word uppercase using:

```
Char[] letters = source.ToCharArray();
letters[0] = Char.ToUpper(letters[0]);
```

And to get the words I was using:

```
Regex.Matches(source, @"\b(\w|['-])+\b"
```

But I am not sure how to put all this together

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Tried anything by now?

Comment: I just updated my question to show what I have tried.

Comment: If minLength is 2, why is `"is"` too short to be title-cased?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Cause OP stated `which length is higher than minLength`

Comment: That's a very unusual definition of "title case". Is it really correct not to capitalise the "mr" and "i" in "last night, mr jones and i were telling each other fairytales."?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: so `minLength` is actually not _min_ enough ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sample code:

```
string input = "i have the car which is very fast";
int minLength = 2;
string regexPattern = string.Format(@"^\w|\b\w(?=\w{{{0}}})", minLength);
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
```

**UPDATE** (for the cases where you have multiple sentences in single string).

```
string input = "i have the car which is very fast. me is slow.";
int minLength = 2;
string regexPattern = string.Format(@"(?<=(^|\.)\s*)\w|\b\w(?=\w{{{0}}})", minLength);
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
```

Output:

```
I Have The Car Which is Very Fast. Me is Slow.
```

You may wish to handle `!`, `?` and other symbols, then you can use the following. You can add as many sentence terminating symbols as you wish.

```
string input = "i have the car which is very fast! me is slow.";
int minLength = 2;
string regexPattern = string.Format(@"(?<=(^|[.!?])\s*)\w|\b\w(?=\w{{{0}}})", minLength);
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
```

**UPDATE (2)** - convert `e-marketing` to `E-Marketing` (consider `-` as valid word symbol):

```
string input = "i have the car which is very fast! me is slow. it is very nice to learn e-marketing these days.";
int minLength = 2;
string regexPattern = string.Format(@"(?<=(^|[.!?])\s*)\w|\b\w(?=[-\w]{{{0}}})", minLength);
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
```

Comment: How to extend your example to all words with length higher than 2 and to first word and words after a dot even if their lenght is smaller then 2?

Comment: I tested and it seems to work fine with one exception. If I have a word like "e-marketing" I would like it to become "E-Marketing" and in this moment I get "e-Marketing". Is it possible to solve this with your example? Thank You

Comment: @MDMoura Added processing of `-`.

Comment: @MDMoura, shouldn't be the correct title case "E-marketing" (similar to "E-commerce")?

Comment: @elgonzo There are no strict rules: http://laurenedwardssv.blogspot.com.tr/2010/03/e-commerce-e-commerce-or-not-so-easy-to.html

Answer (score 1):

English Title Case is extremely complicated. And it is not computable. Period.

The best you can get is a routine that changes all small words according to a list of your preferences. This will still be **wrong** for all **verbal expressions**. While an extended list of variants could capture many of these, some would still be impossible to decide without a semantical analysis. Two examples:

- Running on/On Empty
- Working on/On a Building

The latter gets indeed clear from the context; the former is not. There is a clear difference of meaning, but the computer can't decide which is right.

(Somtimes even humans can't. I asked about the first example here a StackExchnge forum and got no acceptable answer..)

Here is a list is replacements I like; but some four-letter words (no pun intended) are personal choices. Also some might argue that **all** types of numerics, like *any*, *all*, *few* should be capitalized.

This is anything but elegant, in fact it is an embarassement of sorts. But it works for me rather well, so I use it on a regular basis and have fed 100k+ titles through it..:

```
public string ETC(string title)
{  // english title capitalization
    if (title == null) return "";

    string s = title.Trim().Replace('`', '\'');      // change apo to tick mark

    TextInfo UsaTextInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    s = UsaTextInfo.ToTitleCase(s);              // caps for all words

    // a list of exceptions one way or the other..
    s = s.Replace(" A ", " a ");
    s = s.Replace(" also ", " Also ");
    s = s.Replace(" An ", " an ");
    s = s.Replace(" And ", " and ");
    s = s.Replace(" as ", " As ");
    s = s.Replace(" At ", " at ");
    s = s.Replace(" be ", " Be ");
    s = s.Replace(" But ", " But ");
    s = s.Replace(" By ", " by ");
    s = s.Replace(" For ", " for ");
    s = s.Replace(" From ", " from ");
    s = s.Replace(" if ", " If ");
    s = s.Replace(" In ", " in ");
    s = s.Replace(" Into ", " into ");
    s = s.Replace(" he ", " He ");
    s = s.Replace(" has ", " Has ");
    s = s.Replace(" had ", " Had ");
    s = s.Replace(" is ", " Is ");
    s = s.Replace(" my ", " My ");
    s = s.Replace("   ", "  ");                // no triple spaces
    s = s.Replace("'N'", "'n'");          // Rock 'n' Roll
    s = s.Replace("'N'", "'n'");         // Rock 'n Roll
    s = s.Replace(" no ", " No ");
    s = s.Replace(" Nor ", " nor ");
    s = s.Replace(" Not ", " not ");
    s = s.Replace(" Of ", " of ");
    s = s.Replace(" Off ", " off ");
    s = s.Replace(" On ", " on ");
    s = s.Replace(" Onto ", " onto ");
    s = s.Replace(" Or ", " or ");
    s = s.Replace(" O'c ", " O'C ");
    s = s.Replace(" Over ", " over ");
    s = s.Replace(" so ", " So ");
    s = s.Replace(" To ", " to ");
    s = s.Replace(" that ", " That ");
    s = s.Replace(" this ", " This ");
    s = s.Replace(" thus ", " Thus ");
    s = s.Replace(" The ", " the ");
    s = s.Replace(" Too ", " too ");
    s = s.Replace(" when ", " When ");
    s = s.Replace(" With ", " with ");
    s = s.Replace(" Up ", " up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Yet ", " yet ");
    // a few(!) verbal expressions
    s = s.Replace(" Get up ", " Get Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Give up ", " Give Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Givin' up ", " Givin' Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Grow up ", " Grow Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Hung up ", " Hung Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Make up ", " Make Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Wake Me up ", " Wake Me Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Mixed up ", " Mixed Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Shut up ", " Shut Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Stand up ", " Stand Up ");            
    s = s.Replace(" Wind up ", " Wind Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Wake up ", " Wake Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Come up ", " Come Up ");
    s = s.Replace(" Working on ", " Working On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Waiting on ", " Waiting On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Turn on ", " Turn On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Move on ", " Move On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Keep on ", " Keep On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Bring It on ", " Bring It On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Hold on ", " Hold On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Hang on ", " Hang On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Go on ", " Go On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Coming on ", " Coming On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Come on ", " Come On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Call on ", " Call On ");
    s = s.Replace(" Trust in ", " Trust In ");
    s = s.Replace(" Fell in ", " Fell In ");
    s = s.Replace(" Falling in ", " Falling In ");
    s = s.Replace(" Fall in ", " Fall In ");
    s = s.Replace(" Faith in ", " Faith In ");
    s = s.Replace(" Come in ", " Come In ");
    s = s.Replace(" Believe in ", " Believe In ");



    return s.Trim();
}
```

Note that there are still quite a few rules that can't be implemented like this.

Some basic rules are not so hard: Capitalize the 1st and last word. All verbs (*Is*), adjectives (*Red*), promouns (*He*), nouns (*Ace*) and numbers (*One*), even if they have less than 3 (or 4) letters.

But the Exceptions are hard, e.g.: Don't capitalize prepositions when they are part or a **verbal expression**...

Example 1: 'Working on/On a Building' - You have to know that it is a gospel song to decide that it is 'On'.

Example 2: 'Running On/on Empty'. Could mean 'Running On'  or 'Running (with gas indictor) 'on Empty'.

So in the end you will have to live with a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative (and naive) solution that does not require a regular expression would be to use the String.Split method and a `List.Select` function to *map* the complex condition:

```
var text = @"i have the car which is very fast. me is slow.";
var length = 2;
var first = true; // first word in the sentence
var containsDot = false; // previous word contains a dot
var result = text
                .Split(' ')
                .ToList()
                .Select (p => 
                    {
                        if (first)
                        {
                            p = FirstCharToUpper(p);
                            first = false;
                        }
                        if (containsDot)
                        {
                            p = FirstCharToUpper(p);
                            containsDot = false;
                        }
                        containsDot = p.Contains(".");
                        if (p.Length > length)
                        {
                            return FirstCharToUpper(p);
                        }
                        return p;
                    })
                .Aggregate ((h, t) => h + " " + t);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The output is:

```
I Have The Car Which is Very Fast. Me is Slow.
```

The `FirstCharToUpper` method is from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case):

```
public static string FirstCharToUpper(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        throw new ArgumentException("ARGH!");
    return input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", input.Skip(1));
}
```

The drawback of this solution: the more complex the condition, the more complex / unreadable would be the select statement, but it is an alternative to regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which uses a `StringBuilder` and pure string methods and does not need to use regex, so it should be quite efficient:

```
public static string ToTitleCase(string input, int minLength = 0)
{
    TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
    string titleCaseDefault = ti.ToTitleCase(input);
    if (minLength == 0)
        return titleCaseDefault;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(titleCaseDefault.Length);
    int wordCount = 0;
    char[] wordSeparatorChars = " \t\n.,;-:".ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < titleCaseDefault.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = titleCaseDefault[i];
        bool nonSpace = !char.IsWhiteSpace(c);
        if (nonSpace)
        {
            wordCount++;
            int firstSpace = titleCaseDefault.IndexOfAny(wordSeparatorChars, i);
            int endIndex = firstSpace >= 0 ? firstSpace : titleCaseDefault.Length;
            string word = titleCaseDefault.Substring(i, endIndex - i);
            if (wordCount == 1) // first word upper
                sb.Append(word);
            else
                sb.Append(word.Length < minLength ? word.ToLower() : ti.ToTitleCase(word));
            i = endIndex - 1;
        }
        else
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You sample data:

```
string text =  "the car is very fast";
string output = ToTitleCase(text, 3);
```