# Built-in method to convert a string to title case in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

The .NET *Framework* has a method [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx).

Is there something equivalent in .NET Core?

Edit: I'm looking for a built-in method in .NET Core.

Comment: Here is the code in the Reference Source, but it doesn't look trivial to copy to your own project. May be you could try, though. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/textinfo.cs,5f96501d72edadce

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform string to title case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860116/transform-string-to-title-case)

Comment: @Eser not a dupe, that Q has nothing to do with .NET Core

Comment: @mxmissile Regex is not available in .NET Core?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET Standard 2.0 added [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/v2.0.0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Globalization/TextInfo.cs#L556)), so you can use it in .NET Core 2.0.

For .NET Core 1.x support, however, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 26):

You can implement your own extension method:

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
    {
        var tokens = str.Split(new[] { " ", "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (var i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            var token = tokens[i];
            tokens[i] = token == token.ToUpper()
                ? token 
                : token.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + token.Substring(1).ToLower();
        }

        return string.Join(" ", tokens);
    }
}
```

Credit: blatently copied form this [gist](https://gist.github.com/celestocalculus/781edee5e0c16a1e9ccf57975e055334)*.

*Added the bit for acronyms [Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVYfg6).

Comment: This does not do "proper" title casing, however the old .net method did not either.

Comment: the OP request a replacement for `TextInfo.ToTitleCase`, not for a _proper title casing_, so this answer is correct. And also works well.

Comment: This solution doesn't handle all of the cases that ToTitleCase handled. See my solution.

Comment: Why would you convert all instances of `-` to ` `? That's clearly a bug.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Did you read the rest of the code? Did you actually try running it?

Answer (score 11):

It seems there is no such method built-in to .NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, still in October 2016, .NET Core does not provide us with a `ToTitleCase` method.

I created one myself that works for my own needs. You can adjust it by adding your own delimiters to the regular expressions.
Replace `_cultureInfo` with the `CultureInfo` instance that is applicable to you.

```
public static class TextHelper
{
     private static readonly CultureInfo _cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

     public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
     {
         var tokens = Regex.Split(_cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToLower(str), "([ -])");

         for (var i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
         {
             if (!Regex.IsMatch(tokens[i], "^[ -]$"))
             {
                 tokens[i] = $"{_cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToUpper(tokens[i].Substring(0, 1))}{tokens[i].Substring(1)}";
             }
         }

         return string.Join("", tokens);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Try removing the `ToLower()` method if that works for your specific needs.

Comment: I don't know what you mean?  Removing ToLower causes compilation errors. ToLower and ToUpper are the only options I see. Again this solution doesn't handle acronyms.

Comment: Throws an exception on strings terminating with whitespace.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I guess a proper `.Trim()` around the string at the beginning of the method would do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

I created a [github](https://github.com/DeadlyChambers/ToTitleCase/blob/master/Tests/StringExtension.cs) for the extension with tests, and a [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVYfg6) that includes the other solutions from this post. You will have to uncomment to lines to see what the other solutions output. This solution has covered all scenarios that came to mind. You can verify these in the tests on the git or on the fiddle. I suggest you use this solution if you want to get similar output to the TextInfo.ToTitleCase in non .NET Core.

```
 public static class StringExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Should capitalize the first letter of each word. Acronyms will stay uppercased.
    /// Anything after a non letter or number will keep be capitalized. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
    {
        var tokens = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (var ti = 0; ti < tokens.Length; ti++)
        {
            var token = tokens[ti];
            if (token == token.ToUpper())
                stringBuilder.Append(token + " ");
            else
            {
                var previousWasSeperator = false;
                var previousWasNumber = false;
                var ignoreNumber = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < token.Length; i++)
                {

                    if (char.IsNumber(token[i]))
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(token[i]);
                        previousWasNumber = true;
                    }
                    else if (!char.IsLetter(token[i]))
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(token[i]);
                        previousWasSeperator = true;
                    }
                    else if ((previousWasNumber && !ignoreNumber) || previousWasSeperator)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(char.ToUpper(token[i]));
                        previousWasSeperator = false;
                        previousWasNumber = false;
                    }
                    else if (i == 0)
                    {
                        ignoreNumber = true;
                        stringBuilder.Append(char.ToUpper(token[i]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ignoreNumber = true;
                        stringBuilder.Append(char.ToLower(token[i]));
                    }
                }
                stringBuilder.Append(" ");
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in .net core

```
 public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokens = str.Split(new[] { " ", "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string final = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
                {
                    var token = tokens[i];

                    string first = token.Substring(0, 1);
                    string remaining = token.Substring(1, token.Length - 1);

                    final +=  first.ToUpper() + remaining.ToLower()+" ";

                }

                return final;
            }
            catch {
                return "";
            }
        }
```