# All UPPERCASE to SentenceCase

Tags: c#, t4

I have a database that has tables in all CAPITALS eg - TABLENAME.

In my tt file I want to convert these to names to Sentence Case eg - TableName

Has anyone had any success in doing this before?

If all else failed I guess i could capitalise the first letter eg - Tablename would be better than all capitals.

Comment: Check out the .NET Humanizr on GitHub: https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer

Comment: Seems like this would be incredibly prone to an early false positive.  You would be making a best guess as to what the word composition is.  So for instance, consider ICELAND.  Should it be IceLand, Iceland or even Ice land?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: May help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case-in-c-sharp

Comment: Perhaps an odd question, but are there really so many tables that you can't do it manually?

Comment: unless you have some identifier in word to make it as Capital as suggested by @Mike JM its really difficult to achieve what you expect! Else the obvious option would be RENAME

Comment: Yes there is well over 100 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean is the camel case but in your case it's not possible as your program can't possibly guess whether it should be TableName or TablenAme, unless you teach your application all the words in English, at least the ones that are mostly used in software engineering. The .NET Humanizr does something different from what you need, it breaks (well the String extension) long words like "TheVariableThatKeepsNumberOfAttempts"  into separate words to create a human readable sentence. But as you can see, this word itself follows camel-case pattern and it's not hard to instruct the program to split the word from where the letters are capital.
If it's not too late, you can change your table names from TABLENAME to TABLE_NAME, so that you can easily do what you want on the code side.

Comment: Or do I mean pascal case? I really didn't think it was easily possible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression block. In expression block in t4 template. You can write c# code and hence ToUpper() will work and using statements you can add. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126545.aspx

```
<#= … #>)
```