# Making first letter of a textbox upper case

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with this code. I want it to make the first letter of the Textbox upper case, but if the textbox is empty the program crashes. I know the problem is to do with the length of the substring, so if anyone can help me fix this it would be great!
NB: The name of the textbox is richTextBoxGuess and this code runs every time the text in the textbox changes.

```
if (char.IsLower(Convert.ToChar(richTextBoxGuess.Text.Substring(0, 1))) ) // Checks if first letter is lower case
{
    richTextBoxGuess.Text = richTextBoxGuess.Text.Replace(richTextBoxGuess.Text.Substring(0, 1), richTextBoxGuess.Text.ToUpper()); // Changes first letter to uppercase
    richTextBoxGuess.SelectionStart = 2; // Puts cursor after first letter
}
```

Comment: Just check the textbox to see if it is empty first.  `if (richTextBoxGuess.text != "" && ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string to title case in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Oh thank you, that worked. I'm quite new to C# so I feel a bit stupid because it was that obvious!

Comment: Note that changing the Text property of a RTB will destroy its formatting!

Comment: If your are using a `TextBox` you should not call it `richTextBoxGuess` and if you are using a `RichTextBox` you should not talk about it as a `TextBox` all the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not destroy the previous formatting of the content:

```
private void richTextBoxGuess _TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBoxGuess .Text.Length <= 0) return;
    string s = richTextBoxGuess.Text.Substring(0, 1);
    if (s != s.ToUpper())
    {
        int curSelStart = richTextBoxGuess.SelectionStart;
        int curSelLength = richTextBoxGuess.SelectionLength;
        richTextBoxGuess.SelectionStart = 0;
        richTextBoxGuess.SelectionLength = 1;
        richTextBoxGuess.SelectedText = s.ToUpper();
        richTextBoxGuess.SelectionStart = curSelStart;
        richTextBoxGuess.SelectionLength = curSelLength;
    }
}
```

Note that it doesn't not keep track of the changes and will not restore them when you keep adding at the front..

If you need culture invariance use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` parameter of `ToUpper()`!

Answer (score 2):

Check if the richTextBoxGuess is null or empty

```
if( richTextBoxGuess != ""){ // or different from null
     if (char.IsLower(Convert.ToChar(richTextBoxGuess.Text.Substring(0, 1))) ){
             //your code
     }
}
```

Comment: Note that changing the Text property of a RTB will destroy its formatting!

Answer (score 1):

Write this extension method:

```
public static string CapitalizeFirstLetter(this string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return input;
    }

    return input.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + input.Substring(1);
}
```

And then use it as

```
richTextBoxGuess.Text = richTextBoxGuess.Text.CapitalizeFirstLetter();
```

Comment: FYI the second `Substring` can use the overload that just takes the starting index and goes to the end of the string.

Comment: Note that changing the Text property of a RTB will destroy its formatting!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void _capitalizeFirstWord(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
           if (_richTB.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
            {
                e.KeyChar = char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
            }
        }
```

If you want to capitalize every word

```
char _pre,_cur;
_pre=' ';
 private void _capitalizeEveryWord(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
           _cur = e.KeyChar;
           if (_richTB.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
            {
                e.KeyChar = char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
            }
            e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == ' ' && (!(_cur == _pre)) || e.KeyChar == '.' &&                  (!(_pre == _cur)));
            _pre=_cur

        }
```