# While entering text into the text box I want the first letter of the text to be capitalized automatically

Tags: c#, textbox, capitalization

I want to make an event that when entering text into the text box the first letter of the text to be capitalized automatically in fastest way.

Comment: Do you want an event that you use instead of TextChanged event for instance or do you just need logic to put inside an event like that to capitalize the first letter? Second question what type of application are you working with?

Comment: I want to develop a windowsapp. ِYou offer to me which way is better ? I want to when a user that input values in textboxs.It first letter convert to capital and so i want to know how convert the first letter of all list items to capital letter ?

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, some really neat advanced ways but I'd recommend taking a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612444/making-first-letter-of-a-textbox-upper-case

Comment: Please call me how to do this works that i informing to you. 1- how to do this by textchange evet. 2-how to do it by a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something simple like this:

create a text_changed event on the text box

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      {
        if ((textBox1.Text.Length) == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text[0].ToString().ToUpper();
            textBox1.Select(2, 1);

        }
      }
    }
```

Should you have issues with the formatting of the text due to other requirements, than it needs to be done in a different way.