# C# Dealing with whitespaces

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, char, whitespace

I have an input string that gets put into *result*, which is then converted into a *char[]* from there I made the first letter a capital letter. My question is in the for statement I am trying to put a space before each capital letter. **It does not recognize *insert()* due to *char[]* what is the replacement for this?**

**I also have a problem being my first letter a capital it will input a space on the first word. How can I solve this issue and implement it into my code.**

Example:

"HelloThere"

Output

" Hello There"

Do I insert it into a new string name? and return that instead of output e.g. char[] final would be the final return.

Finally, having to add spaces before each capital, **how can I apply a rule that only 1 space is allowed?**

Comment: try replacing your double quote marks \ speech marks for single quote marks as this is what indicates a char

Comment: Side note: code would be simple if you could use `StringBuilder`... Alternatively simple regex matching {lowerCase,upperCase} pair would make it into one statement.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I am new to this, if you could possibly use my code as an example and post an answer would be great thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regex for inserting spaces before each capitalized letter:

```
var result = "HelloThere";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(result, @"\s*(\p{Lu})", " $1"));
```

Note that `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace characters, and `\p{Lu}` matches any Unicode uppercase letter. The uppercase letter is captured into Group 1, and space is added in front of the uppercase letter string with the help of the replacement string.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/iNv5DL)

Do not forget to add a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` directive.

Here is a [full example](http://ideone.com/2J4jKe) with the regex declared in a static class:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = "HelloThere";
    Console.WriteLine(Regexes.rxAddSpaceBeforeCapital.Replace(result, " $1"));
    result = "Hello  There";
    Console.WriteLine(Regexes.rxAddSpaceBeforeCapital.Replace(result, " $1"));
}

public static class Regexes
{
    public static readonly Regex rxAddSpaceBeforeCapital = new Regex(@"\s*(\p{Lu})", RegexOptions.Compiled);    
}
```

Comment: From the code if Regex.Replace(result, @"(\S)(\p{Lu})", "$1 $2")); does the function of my for loop, how can I implement this to my code?

Comment: For example, if my stirng has double space how can I apply the rule of each space must only be 1 space.

Comment: What are possible, sample input strings? I see I might have a bit misunderstood the goal: you need to add the space even in the beginning of the string,  right?

Comment: I have a test unit that contains string ""Hello  Test" this is double white space and another test unit that contais "HelloTest" no space.

Comment: If you could tell me where to place the code you provide that would be great and also from the regex this makes my for statement redundant so i can remove that now?

Comment: I guess all your code can be replaced with it. Also, you can declare the regex as a public static readonly field in a static class, compile it, and use in any loop without efficiency issues.

Comment: My issue is still that if its double space it doesnt pass the test, How can I force multiple spaces to convert to ONLY 1.

Comment: [`"Hello<SPACE><SPACE>There"` -> `Hello<SPACE>There`](http://ideone.com/2J4jKe). `\s*` does it for you, as it matches 0 or more, but as many as possible, whitespaces.

Comment: Hm but the test unit with double space has not passed and if /s* does this, I dont know whats wrong with it

Comment: Have a look at [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b+%5d*(%5cp%7bLu%7d)&i=Hello++Test%0d%0aHelloTest&r=+%241). Go to the *Context* tab, and see the actual replacement result. It does the same in my code demo. If it does not work for you, please post this code in the question so that I could have a look.

Comment: Come on, you did not assign it to any variable! `var output =
        whitespace.Replace(result, "$1 $2");`

Comment: Where do I declare it, I complete miss that, it says I cannot convert string to char[]

Comment: I'd even say - replace all the code above with `return Regex.Replace(result, @"\s*(\p{Lu})", " $1");`. If you do not feel comfortable with static classes, use this static `Regex.Replace` method.

Comment: I have used Regex replace but it says I cannot conver string to char[]. The regex itself works but I have a char[] instead of a string

Comment: You do not need that any longer. Discard any conversion to `char[]`. Please see this demo: http://ideone.com/3m9i4n

Comment: The reason I had converted it into char[] was to change all first letter of each word to capital but I have removed that and there is a space before each capital letter e.g " Hello There" and also " Hello there"

Comment: Well, I seem to sleep already. All you need is: 1) use your code up until you get `HelloThere` or `Hello<SPACE><SPACE>There`, 2) Use my regex to merge/add a space before.

Comment: Your regex works it outputs as required but I have a new problem. I am currently looking for the solution. 1) First letter of word is no longer capital 2) space in each word with capital even the first word

Comment: That is why you should have provided *exact* input and *expected output*. Do you want to get `Hello<SPACE>There` instead of `<SPACE>Hello<SPACE>There`? You can use `(?<!^)\s*(\p{Lu})` regex then. What do you pass into the method as arguments? **Post full relevant code**.

Comment: I see thank you very much for your help, do you have any idea how I can convert any first letter to a capital?

Comment: Have a look at [Converting string to title case in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case-in-c-sharp) SO post. More details at [MSDN TextInfo.ToTitleCase Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I have a question lastly, if my title is "The Great and the Greater", I used CultureInfo but that just made all first letter of each word capital, how can I make it follow so that the format is similar to the title provided?

Comment: This has little to do with inserting whitespaces before uppercase letters. I suspect you had this same problem before with your own code. This is not good when you describe one problem but go on asking to solve all issues you have. My last hint: use a case-insensitive whole word search for the words that must remain lowercase and make them lowercase. You will need a regex replace with a match evaluator. Something like `var t = Regex.Replace(output, @"(?i)\b(?:an?d?|of|the)\b)", m => m.Value.ToLower());`

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code, it will replace white space between each Camel Case words :

```
var inputStr= "HemantPatel";
var result = Regex.Replace(inputStr, "([a-z])([A-Z])", @"$1 $2"); //Category Name
```

Output will be : "Hemant Patel"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code similar to what you proposed, try this, otherwise choose one of the other brief good solutions proposed:

```
// Example string.
string result = "       helloThere,  ThisIs      AnExampleString       ";
// Remove leading and trailing white spaces.
result = result.Trim();
// Capitalize first letter.
result = char.ToUpper(result[0]) + result.Substring(1);

// Replace long white spaces with just one white space,
// e.g. "Hello      World" -> "Hello World"
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"[ ]{2,}", " ");

// Insert spaces before capital letters.
for (var i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLower(result[i - 1]) && char.IsUpper(result[i]))
    {
        result = result.Insert(i, " ");
    }
}
// OUTPUT: "Hello There, This Is An Example String"
```

By the way, in you code the `Insert` method wasn't working because it is an extension method that isn't defined for type `char[]`.