# C# Capitalise First Letter of String - More effective method?

Tags: c#, parsing

I have some code that does what I want it to do but I want to know if there's a quicker way to do what I want.

The user will input their names and I want to make sure that their name is as close to this format as possible:

- john > John
- julie > Julie

My code:

```
// First Name
s_in_GetUserFirstName = s_in_GetUserFirstName.ToLower();
c_in_UserFirstNameFirstChar = s_in_GetUserFirstName[0];
s_in_UserFirstNameFirstChar = c_in_UserFirstNameFirstChar.ToString().ToUpper();
s_in_GetUserFirstName = s_in_GetUserFirstName.Remove(0, 1);
s_in_GetUserFirstName = s_in_UserFirstNameFirstChar + s_in_GetUserFirstName;
// Last Name
s_in_GetUserLastName = s_in_GetUserLastName.ToLower();
c_in_UserLastNameFirstChar = s_in_GetUserLastName[0];
s_in_UserLastNameFirstChar = c_in_UserLastNameFirstChar.ToString().ToUpper();
s_in_GetUserLastName = s_in_GetUserLastName.Remove(0, 1);
s_in_GetUserLastName = s_in_UserLastNameFirstChar + s_in_GetUserLastName;
```

What I do is split the string into two parts, the first char and the rest. I capitalise the first character and remove that character from the string. Then I combine strings into one.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1206029/563532 - This formatting is typically called 'Title Case' or 'Proper Case'

Comment: That is perfect, thank you!

Comment: LINQ: This would work too:) 

var str =
    s 
    .ToCharArray()
    .Select((c,i) => i == 0 ? Char.ToUpper(c) : Char.ToLower(c))
    .Select(c => c.ToString())
    .Aggregate((c,n) => c+n)
;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single line like this

```
test.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()+test.Substring(1);
```

Or do this as Rob suggested in comment

[Converting string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case-in-c-sharp/1206029#1206029)