# Trouble with Linq List

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to Linq and was wondering if someone could assist me. I'm trying to get my code to where I enter something it will change the first letter or any word to uppercase. The teacher asked us to use Linq and to display the results at the end.

For example, when it says "What is your first name:" let's say I enter "mark" or "mark gallows" it will change it to "Mark" and "Mark Gallows". I want to be able to enter it without mark being embedded in the code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        string street;
        string city;
        string state;
        string zip;
        Console.Write("What is your first name: ");
        firstname= Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("What is your last name:");
        lastname= Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("What is your street name:");
        street= Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("What is your city name:");
        city= Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("What is your state name:");
        state= Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("What is your zip code:");
        zip= Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string UppercaseWords(string value)
    {
        char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("firstName"); 
        items.Add("lastName"); 
        items.Add("street"); 
        items.Add("city");
        items.Add("state");
        items.Add("zip");


        var x =
     from item in items
     let UppercaseWords = item.ToCharArray()
     select UppercaseWords;

      foreach (var item in x)
            Console.Write("{0} ", item);
        if (array.Length >= 1)
        {
            if (char.IsLower(array[0]))
            {
                array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
            {
                if (char.IsLower(array[i]))
                {
                    array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return new string(array);
    }
```

How can I display the results after I enter them in to see the changes?

Comment: you don't need linq. this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
s = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s);
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate answer.