# How to convert nested JSON Single Value Arrays to a Single Value in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables, json.net

I'm currently working on a solution that will allow users to search for a medicine and populate a datatable with the results. The data comes from the Openfda API. This works but unfortunately returns many duplicate rows. While in the process of trying to suppress the duplicate rows I found that the process may be failing due to the fact that it's trying to compare arrays instead of strings. Unfortunately, Openfda sends almost all strings as arrays even if it's not an array. Is there any way to convert the single value arrays to a single value in either the Model or Controller class (preferably but not mandatory) before returning the JSON to the datatable?

Code snippet of raw JSON:

```
      ],
  "other_safety_information": [
    "each teaspoonful contains: sodium 6 mg do not use if tape imprinted with “SEALED FOR YOUR PROTECTION” on top and bottom flaps of carton is not intact. store between 20° and 25°C (68° and 77°F)"
  ],
  "openfda": {
    "product_ndc": [
      "11523-4360"
    ],
    "is_original_packager": [
      true
    ],
    "package_ndc": [
      "11523-4360-1",
      "11523-4360-3",
      "11523-4360-2",
      "11523-4360-5",
      "11523-4360-4",
      "11523-4360-7",
      "11523-4360-6"
    ],
    "generic_name": [
      "LORATADINE"
    ],
    "spl_set_id": [
      "170061e9-e529-4ff0-e054-00144ff8d46c"
    ],
    "upc": [
      "0041100811028"
    ],
    "brand_name": [
      "Children Claritin Allergy"
    ],
    "manufacturer_name": [
      "Bayer HealthCare LLC."
    ],
```

JSON sent to datatable:

```
{"data":{"Results":[{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Children Claritin Allergy"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin-D 24 Hour"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE AND PSEUDOEPHEDRINE SULFATE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin Reditabs"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin-D 24 Hour"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE AND PSEUDOEPHEDRINE SULFATE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin Liqui-Gels"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin-D 12 Hour"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE AND PSEUDOEPHEDRINE SULFATE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin Reditabs"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Lil Drug Store Claritin Non-Drowsy, 24 Hour"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}},{"Openfda":{"BrandName":["Claritin"],"GenericName":["LORATADINE"]}}]}}
```

MVC Model:

```
        public class Openfda
    {
        [JsonProperty("brand_name")]
        public List<string> BrandName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("generic_name")]
        public List<string> GenericName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("openfda")]
        public Openfda Openfda { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

MVC Controller:

```
    public ActionResult SearchMeds(string id)
    {
        var medicine = id;

        string url =
            "https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&limit=100&search=brand_name:";
        if (medicine != null)
        {


            MedSearch.Root model = null;
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var task = client.GetAsync(url + medicine);

            var response = task.Result;
            var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MedSearch.Root>(jsonString.Result);

            //Debug.WriteLine(model.Results[0].Openfda.BrandName[0]);
            //Debug.WriteLine(model.Results[0].Openfda.GenericName[0]);

            return Json(new { data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { data = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        //return PartialView("_CreatePartial");
    }
```

Datatable:

```
     var oTable = $('#MedicineSearch').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Medicines/SearchMeds/" + rowdata,
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json",
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                    var temp, data = [];
                    var domain, domains = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < json.data.Results.length; i++) {
                        temp = json.data.Results[i];

                        domain = temp.Openfda.BrandName;
                        console.log(domain);
                        if (~domains.indexOf(domain)) {
                            this.nodes().to$().attr('excluded', 'true');
                        } else {
                            domains.push(domain);
                            data.push(temp);
                        }

                        //data.push(temp);
                        //console.log(temp);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            "destroy": true,
            "paging": true,
            "searching": false,
            "select": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Openfda.BrandName" },
                { "data": "Openfda.GenericName" }
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable":
                    "You do not have any Medicines, please click on <b>Actions - Add New</b> button"
            }

        });
```

dataSrc is where I'm trying to suppress the duplicate rows. It's capturing the data but not following the "IF" statement because I'm assuming it's trying to compare arrays instead of the actual values and simply passing on to the "else" statement.

I believe that if I can convert the arrays to values I can better resolve the duplicate rows. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** Here is the working version.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [HandleJsonException]
    public ActionResult SearchMeds(Medicines.Search data)
    {
        TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        string url =
            "https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?limit=100&search=";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var task = client.GetAsync(url + data.searchterm + '"' + data.medicine + '"');
        var response = task.Result;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() },
            };
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Medicines.Root>(jsonString.Result, settings);
            var distinctResults = model.Results
                .Select(r => new
                {
                    BrandName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(r.Openfda.BrandName.SingleOrDefault().ToLower()),
                    GenericName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(r.Openfda.GenericName.SingleOrDefault().ToLower())
                })
                .Distinct();
            var returnModel =
                new
                {
                    data = new { Results = distinctResults.Select(Openfda => new { Openfda }) },
                };
            return Json(returnModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        return new JsonResult() { Data = response.StatusCode, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Datatable:

```
        $('#btnMedSearch').on('click', function () {
        var brandbutton = document.getElementById("brand");
        var genericbutton = document.getElementById("generic");
        var term = "";
        var rowdata = new Array;
        if (brandbutton.checked) { term = "brand_name:" }
        else if (genericbutton.checked) { term = "substance_name:" }
        $("#result").html("");
        rowdata.medicine = $("#MedNameToSearch").val();
        if (rowdata.medicine !== "") {
            rowdata.searchterm = term;
            var oTable2 = $('#MedicineSearch').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Medicines/SearchMeds/",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "data": rowdata,
                    "dataSrc": function (json) {
                        try {
                            var temp, data = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < json.data.Results.length; i++) {
                                temp = json.data.Results[i].Openfda;
                                data.push(temp);
                            }
                            return data;
                        } catch (e) {
                        };
                    },
                    "error": function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var msg = "";
                        if (jqXhr.status === 0) {
                            msg = 'Unable to connect. Please Try Again Later.';
                        } else if (jqXhr.status === 404) {
                            msg = 'Your Search Did Not Return Any Results';
                        } else if (jqXhr.status === 400) {
                            msg = 'Please Enter Another Search Term';
                        }
                        if (msg !== "") {
                            oTable2.destroy();
                            $('#MedicineSearch').empty("");
                            $("#result").html(msg);
                        } else {
                            oTable2.destroy();
                            $('#MedicineSearch').empty("");
                            msg = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText);
                            $("#result").html(msg.Message);
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                "destroy": true,
                "paging": true,
                "searching": false,
                "select": true,
                "columns": [
                    { data: "BrandName", title: "Brand Name" },
                    { data: "GenericName", title: "Generic Name/Active Ingredient" }
                ]
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a Medicine to Search for");
        }
    });
```

Comment: In `~domains.indexOf(domain)`, what is the purpose of using `~`? . `indexOf()` method returns `int` value, if it finds searching `string` then it will return actual `index` of `string` else it will return `-1`. So for your case, you should replace `if(~domains.indexOf(domain)) {....}` with `if(domains.indexOf(domain) > -1) {...}`

Comment: I see that your `domain` is an array, so you should be using [`jQuery.inArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) or [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

Comment: 1) Are you sure these single-value arrays are **always** going to have one and only one value?   If they occasionally have more or fewer values then converting them to simple values will make your life harder not easier.  2) Have you considered merging duplicates in the c# code?  3) Can you [edit] your question to share an example of JSON returned by Openfda that has duplicate rows -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: @mmushtaq You are correct... Even though `~domains.indexOf(domain)` worked, i like your implementation of `(domains.indexOf(domain) > -1)` better. I tried using `jQuery.inArray` but it seemed to have difficulty deciding if an Array was in an Array. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dbc They **should** only have one value (from what i've seen so far anyway.) I can't post an example of an Openfda response that includes duplicates, since a search response for "claritin" contains over 1700 lines. The API sends everything it can find for "claritin","CLARITIN","Claritin","Childrens Claritin",etc. You can click [Openfda](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&limit=100&search=brand_name:"claritin") for an example. I would love to merge the duplicates in C# but I don't know of a way to do that with JSON other than a hash set in the model, maybe? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an enhancement to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48334142/3744182) of [Bob Dust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065333/bob-dust) to return an anonymous type with the arrays projected to their single values, you can take advantage of the fact that equality comparison for anonymous types uses [value semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) to return only distinct results by calling [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() },
};
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MedSearch.Root>(jsonString.Result, settings);

var distinctResults = model.Results
    .Select(r => new { BrandName = r.Openfda.BrandName.SingleOrDefault(), GenericName = r.Openfda.GenericName.SingleOrDefault() })
    .Distinct();

var returnModel =
    new
    {
        data = new { Results = distinctResults.Select(Openfda => new { Openfda }) },
    };

return Json(returnModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Using the following simplified models:

```
public class Openfda
{
    public List<string> BrandName { get; set; }
    public List<string> GenericName { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Openfda Openfda { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

When `id = "claritin"`, https://api.fda.gov/ currently returns 15 results, which are compressed down to 7 results with the call to `Distinct()`.

Notes:

- By merging duplicates in the c# code you completely eliminate the need to do this on the client side.
- To deserialize from snake case, rather than marking each property individually with `[JsonProperty("some_snake_case_name")]`, I use [`SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm) to do it for all names automatically.

Comment: One question. Say you search for "tylenol". Some results are returned "title case", some are "uppercase", which throws off the `distinct()`. What's the proper way to convert to "Title Case"? `BrandName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(r.Openfda.BrandName.SingleOrDefault().ToLower())` works but indicates a "possible null reference exception". I can prevent that from happening with `if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)` but didn't know if that's the recommended way to convert to "Title Case." Thank you.

Comment: @Sam.A. - "How can I convert to title case" is really a separate question, and the preferred format for questions on stackoverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  As it turns out, the answer is already here: [Converting string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1206019).  Checking `response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK` is a good idea anyway, if an error is returned then pass that along to the caller.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. With your help, i've been able to get this working properly.

Answer (score 1):

How about converting the arrays to values when they're being serialized to json:

```
            return Json(new {
                data = new {
                    Results = model.Results.Select(i => new {
                        Openfda = new {
                            BrandName = i.Openfda.BrandName.FirstOrDefault(),
                            GenericName = i.Openfda.GenericName.FirstOrDefault()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

btw, this line at client-side script seems unnecessary (or maybe causing error):

```
this.nodes().to$().attr('excluded', 'true');
```

Comment: You are correct, that line was leftover from testing and it did cause an error once the `if` statement began working correctly. Btw, your recommendation does work but i would prefer to not have to bang out the key:value pairs like that. I may not have a choice though. Thank you very much!