# Cannot get a proper ToTitleCase

Tags: c#, string

I've tried three approaches to get a ProperName solution for a string of all CAPS.
Here is my code:

```
string testStr = "SYNDEGAARD";

string result1 = UppercaseFirst(testStr);

string titleCase = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(testStr);
string result2 = titleCase;

CultureInfo culture_info = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo text_info = culture_info.TextInfo;
string result3 = text_info.ToTitleCase(testStr);

private static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
{
    // Check for empty string.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    // Return char and concat substring.
    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

All three results are "SYNDENGAARD".  It never changes to "Syndengaard".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case)

Comment: @Slai - It's not specifically a duplicate. The answer to this question can be found there, but they are not the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update to this

```
return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1).ToLower();
```

Comment: Thanks, ToLower fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you can't get the result you wanted is because `ToTitleCase()` doesn't work if the input string is all in capital letters.

You can try changing `SYNDEGAARD` to `SYNDEGAARDx` and see the difference.

As to why that's the default behavior I am not sure.

Also you forgot to add `ToLower()` in this function to make sure that the preceding texts will be in lowercase.

```
    private static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
    {
        // Check for empty string.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        // Return char and concat substring.
        return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1).ToLower(); // Missing ToLower()
    }
```

EDIT:

Here's why nothing happens for uppercase texts.

[TextInfo.ToTitleCase Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Converts the specified string to title case (except for words that are
>   entirely in uppercase, which are considered to be acronyms).

Answer (score 1):

Use Humanizer, it will provide you with the range of utilities for conversions and manipulate strings, enums, dates, times, timespans, numbers and quantities.

https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer

Nuget Package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer/

```
Var name = "shyam bhagat";
var titleCase = name.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title);
```