# How can I convert a string so that the first character of each word is uppercase and the rest of the characters lowercase?

Tags: c#

So far I have this code that converts every character to uppercase:

```
    public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            var value = (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.ToUpper() : value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

But I would like to just convert the first character of each word. Is there any function that would allow me to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206019/converting-string-to-title-case

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ToTitleCase` like below:

`return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value.ToLower());`

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want this (you can do it in an external function, or even inline.
(external function)

```
public static string FistCharacterToUpper(string input)
    {
        string temp = input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1);
        return temp;
    }
```

Or inline:

```
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.First().ToString().ToUpper() + value.Substring(1) : value;
```

Comment: This will fail if the characters after the first character have uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private string ConvertStrinToCamelStyle(string name)
    {
        string[] strName = name.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        name = "";
        foreach (string strN in strName)
        {
            name += Char.ToUpperInvariant(strN[0]) + strN.Substring(1) + " ";
        }

        return name.Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use chars for this problem :))

```
static string Conv(string inp)
{
   inp = inp[0].ToString().ToUpper() + inp.Substring(1, inp.Length - 1).ToLower();
   return inp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm building a global "utilities" class I can add to any project.  In it is lots of useful functions and I also put extension methods in there.  Thought, maybe making this into an extension method could be useful.

```
public static string ToTitleCase(this string inString) => new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(inString);
```

**Usage:**

```
string test = "wAr aNd pEaCe";

test = test.ToTitleCase();
```